# Can't increasing the value in front end by react. Data comes from mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api

I can't update the value in the front end. I want to decrease the value of quantity when I click delivered.

Here is my code.

```
const handleDelivered = () => {
    const newQuantity = parseInt(inventory.quantity) + 1;
    const makeQuantity = newQuantity;
    console.log(makeQuantity);
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/inventory/${id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ makeQuantity }),
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
};
```

Here is the update operation on the server-side.

```
app.put("/inventory/:id", async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const data = req.body;
        const filter = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
        const options = { upsert: true };
        const updateDoc = {
            $set: {
                ...data,
            },
        };
        const result = await fruitsCollection.updateOne(
            filter,
            updateDoc,
            options
        );
        res.send(result);
    });
```

Here is the code for button:

```
<Card.Link
 onClick={handleDelivered}
 className="btn btn-danger">
 Delivered
</Card.Link>
```

Here is the screenshot:
[If I click the delivered button, the console says it is 13, but UI doesn't update. Also, Restock Item button doesn't increase the quantity](https://i.ibb.co/z2HCY0S/Screenshot-2022-05-04-at-9-36-56-PM.png)

How can I solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't automatically handle model updates for you. You need to handle this yourself or use a library which handles it for you.

Without seeing more code, it's hard to give specific details on how *you* should update your local models, but it might look like this:

```js
const [inventory, setInventory] = useState(defaultInventory)

function handleDelivered() {
    fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then(setInventory)
}
```

assuming the response from the fetch is the entire `fruit` object. If it's a partial, you'll need to merge in the response with the local model.